# A logarithmic integral of order $n$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis

Let $0<\alpha<\beta$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. It is not that difficult for someone to prove that

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log x}{\left ( x+\alpha \right )\left ( x+\beta \right )} \, {\rm d}x = \frac{1}{2 \left ( \beta - \alpha \right )} \left [ \log^2 \beta - \log^2 \alpha \right ] \tag{1}$$

and

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log^2 x}{\left ( x+\alpha \right )\left ( x+\beta \right )} \, {\rm d}x = \frac{\pi^2 \left ( \log \beta - \log \alpha \right ) + \left ( \log^3 \beta - \log^3 \alpha \right )}{3 \left ( \beta - \alpha \right )}  \tag{2}$$

The natural root to follow to crack these is complex analysis ( keyhole contour ) and the result follows without much difficulty. Laplace methods also work. Now, what can we say about this:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log^n x}{\left ( x+\alpha \right )\left ( x+\beta \right )} \, {\rm d}x$$

I've been unable to find a closed form depending on $n$ or even a recursive relation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $${I_n} = \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{{{\ln }^n}x}}{{(x + b)(x + a)}}dx}$$
Then integrate $$f(z) = \frac{{{{(\ln z)}^{n + 1}}}}{{(z + b)(z + a)}}$$ around the keyhold contour, with $\ln x$ a branch cut at positive $x$-axis, gives
$$\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{{{(\ln x)}^{n + 1}}}}{{(x + b)(x + a)}}dx}  - \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{{{(\ln x + 2\pi i)}^{n + 1}}}}{{(x + b)(x + a)}}dx}  = 2\pi i\left[ {\frac{{{{(\ln a + \pi i)}^{n + 1}} - {{(\ln b + \pi i)}^{n + 1}}}}{{b - a}}} \right]$$
Hence $$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\binom{n+1}{k}{{(2\pi i)}^{n + 1 - k}}{I_k}}  = 2\pi i\left[ {\frac{{{{(\ln b + \pi i)}^{n + 1}} - {{(\ln a + \pi i)}^{n + 1}}}}{{b - a}}} \right]$$
which is a desired recurrence relation.